# Pass sensitive data to Nextjs Link component

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a question about Link component from ‘next-Link ’
What should I do if I want pass a sensitive data like a category_id for example, how can I pass it securely to be used in getServerSideProps() function
I don’t want want to use query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide data from URL you can use the `as` property of Next Link :

```js
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: "/myUrl",
    query: { id: "1111" },
  }}
  as="/myUrl"
>
  Go to Page
</Link>;
```

the `url` will be : `http://localhost:3000/myUrl`

but you still can access data :

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
//..
const router = useRouter();
console.log(router.query.id);
```